# How to use twice a reference to another table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

Considering the following classes:

```
public class Unidade
{
    public int UnidadeId { get; set; }
    public string Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class Estrutura
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    …
    public int UnidadeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Unidade Unidade { get; set; }
    …
    public int UnidadeCompraId { get; set; }
    public virtual Unidade UnidadeCompra { get; set; }
    …
  }
```

The query Estruturas.Single(e => e.Id == 120898).Unidade.Descricao will return an error, actually because Estruturas.Single(e => e.Id == 120898).Unidade is null.

The Id (120898) used in this example is valid as there is a valid value of UnidadeId set.

What’s wrong? How can I access de value of Descricao having a valid Estrura?

Comment: You can try eager loading (`Estruturas.Include(e => e.Unidade.Single(e => e.Id == 120898).Unidade.Descricao`) althought your navigation property is setup for lazy loading and the code should work as is (except if there is model configuration issue or the lazy loading / proxy creation is disabled for the context). Do you have any fluent configuration?

Comment: Actually the problem happened the first time in a MVC eager loading and I simplified it isolating the EF pattern for here... It won't work

Comment: If you have null values then change int to int?

Comment: I don't have null values, that's the problem...

Answer (score 0):

In C# 6:

```
struturas.Single(e => e.Id == 120898).Unidade?.Descricao
```

you will gen null if `Unidade` is null

Comment: The problem is that it shouldn't be null... There is a UnidadeId, hence there should be a Unidade...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have lazy loading turned off.  Though that is probably better.  The issue then is you need to .Include before calling .Single or it won't fetch the other table data.

**Edit**

Either that or the Foreign Key to this other table is either not defined at all or setup on the wrong column.  Thus, it ends up trying to link the wrong 2 pieces of data and you end up getting no data found there.

An easy way to test this is to simply do this:

```
 string sql = Estruturas.Where(e => e.Id == 120898).Include(a => a.Unidade).ToString();
```

This will show you the SQL that EF will run, minus the actual parameter value.  Make sure this shows up how you would expect it to look.  You can even just run this query in Sql Server directly with the parameter filled in to make sure you get back the data, too.

Also, you have to have the [Key] defined somewhere for the tables.  The Foreign Key setup assumes it links back to the PK of the other table only.

Comment: This example I generated in LinqPad just to post here. The real issue happened in a MVC app with lazy loading on and the Controller hadthe necessary "Include"...

Comment: Can you post your model class and controller example?

Comment: public class Unidade
    {
        public int UnidadeId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        [Display(Name = "Unidade")]
        public string Apelido { get; set; }

        [StringLength(16)]
        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

    }

Comment: I have no space for the classes but the controller is:

    public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var estruturas = db.Estruturas
                .Include(e => e.Produto)
                .Include(e => e.Sequencia)
                .Include(e => e.Unidade)
                .Include(e => e.UnidadeCompra);

            return View(estruturas.ToList());
        }

Comment: Wait, how if your foreign key defined?